# Mongodb query performance

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-performance

I have a collection with 250K documents and I want to find the last one inserted with a particular property "siteid" which is indexed. This is the query I am using.

```
db.getCollection('txnCollection').find({"siteid":"123456"}).limit(1).sort({"_id":-1})
```

If there is a record it is found quickly.  If there isn't the performance is not quick enough circa 0.8s.

However if I run the query

```
db.getCollection('txnCollection').find({"siteid":"123456"}).limit(1)
```

The performance is really quick even if there is no document with siteid 123456.

It seems silly to run this query then if a record is returned to run the second query to get the record I want - ie. the last inserted one, but I cannot work out a way of doing anything better

For info when I run explain the result I get is

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "txn.txnCollection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "siteid" : {
                "$eq" : "123456"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : -1
            },
            "limitAmount" : 1,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "siteid" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "siteid_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "siteid" : [ 
                                "[\"123456\", \"123456\"]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "XXXXX",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.0.6",
        "gitVersion" : "1ef45a23a4c5e3480ac919b28afcba3c615488f2"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I cannot find a question, please edit so your question is clear

Comment: Am i doing something wrong in the query or the index. Is there a way of finding the most recent record that returns quickly even if one doesn't exist.

Comment: Obviously professor79 is already trying to answer you, so he understood better than me, plz ignore comment

Comment: could you dump indexes?

Answer (score 0):

The point is when `sort` and `limit` is used, `sort` is applied before `limit` is executed..... That means your full query result is sorted and then limited.

Comment: If I take the limit off. Nothing is returned quickly when there are no records with the site id.  If I then sort it.  It is really slow.  It still returns nothing.

Comment: Is there a way of turning this off if it is expensive.  I am worried about performance not really whether a new record has been added since my query started.

Comment: This has go weirder.  I have added another unrelated  index and this has started working now I am getting very quick results even when I am querying a siteid not in the table, but the new index is behaving exactly the same ie. returns quickly if the field exisits or if I leave out the sort, but not if I put the sort in.  When I use explain I get exactly the same result for both the query that is fast and the one that is now slow.  is there something I have to do to indexes to get them to work properly?

Comment: @user3782299 that a bit complicated - I am with you now :-)... could use `hint`  like `query.hint({siteid:1})`  ?

Comment: I don;t think that is the problem.  Look at the explain above.  The index is being used.  I have a fresh update. the query without the sort always runs fast (2ms) even when the search is not successful.  The one with the sort sometimes does, but sometimes is very slow.  I think it may have to do with transactions being inserted whilst the query is executing.

Comment: I don't care about these.  My database is a very simple transaction store. Transactions are being added constantly, but not updated.  I want to see the most recent transaction for a partiular siteid (but do not care if I miss by a few seconds).  I need reads to execute <10ms and the store will get big >750M records (it is only 0.25M) now

Comment: So the question is how do I get the last transaction for a siteid quickly.  Is my index correct.